# xml parse - xpath clarification in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, for-xml-path

How should i get the `Link` value from the below xml

XML Content

```
<document-instance system="abc.org" number-of-pages="6" desc="Drawing" link="www.google.com">
        <document-format-options>
          <document-format>application/pdf</document-format>
          <document-format>application/tiff</document-format>
        </document-format-options>
        <document-section name="DRAWINGS" start-page="1" />
      </document-instance>
```

i traverse update desc attribute after that i'm struggle

```
 XPathExpression firstPageUrl = xPath.compile("//document-instance/@desc=\"Drawing\"]");
```

Expected output : retrieve the Link value

```
www.google.com
```

Comment: you should query for @link instead of @desc=["drawing"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    File file = new File("path to file");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String expression = "//document-instance/@link";
    Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    String url= node.getTextContent();
```

Comment: That leading "//" is quite unnecessary - no need to search the whole document if you know the document-instance is the outermost element.